# Data Science using Vim

Tags: python, numpy, vim, scipy, vim-plugin

I have found some great solution for setup and learning vim for python and framework around it (Django, Flask, Pyramid, etc ), but is it possible to setup it for Data Science.
I suppose coding would not be a problem,  but what about visualizing, is there some libraries I can install.
Thank You.

Comment: Data Science  using Vim could be used when you are a beginner but as you work more and more in this domain you need to deal with lot of data and visualizing the data and manipulating the data mostly using pandas and matplotlib. most of the people use jupyter-notebooks and  pycharm.

Answer (score 1):

[matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org) is a popular and easy to use python library for visualisation, as is Stanford's [seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/), which extends matplotlib and is very useful for statistical analysis.

If you like D3.js, there is a [python library, d3py](https://github.com/mikedewar/d3py), that you can use (for interactive javascript based graphs).

Comment: Yes I use matplotlib, and scipy, numpy packages whit sublime text 3, I was curious about me doing the same stuff whit vim, and i will check seaborn and D3.js, tnx

Answer (score 1):

People use different tools for data science. They can use R, SAS, Python, and even EViews or Excel. So I dont think there is a one-for-all vim plugin for data science. However, you can find vim plugin for specific tools, like for R you can use vim-r-plugin: http://www.lepem.ufc.br/jaa/vim-r-plugin.html

It is not possible to do similar visualization in VIM like in other IDEs say RStudio. Vim's visualization function is based on ncurses and don't forget Vim is essentially a text editor. You should use other IDEs for the fancy visualization.

Comment: Ah yes, that's the cache, I was thinking about derivatives for vim so I can make some kind of IDE for Data science, and I am interesting in using python for Data Science, but nevertheless I like your answer. I will continue exploring, thanks.